# Using fseek() To Update a Binary File

Tags: c, file, binary, fwrite, fseek

I have looked and looked online for help on using fseek() efficiently, but no matter what I do, I am still not receiving the right results. Basically I am reading from a file of animals that have an "age" parameter. If the age is -1, then upon adding to this binary file, I should use fseek() to find the first -1 in the file and overwriting that entire line with new information that the user inputs. I have an array that traverses and finds all of the holes at the beginning of the file, and it is working correctly. My issue is that it is updating the new animal and putting each one in the next empty slot with age -1, but when I go to refresh my file, all of the animals are appended to the end, even though their id's are the id's of the once empty slots. Here is my code:

```
void addingAnimal(FILE *file, struct animal ani, int * availableHoles) {
    int i;
    int offset = ((sizeof(int) + sizeof(ani)) * ani.id -1);
    if (availableHoles[0] != 0) {
        fseek(file, offset, SEEK_SET);
        ani.id = availableHoles[0];
        fwrite & ani, sizeof(ani), 1, file);
        for (i = 0; i < sizeof(availableHoles) -1; i++) {
            availableHoles[i] = avialablesHoles[i+1];
        }
}
```

The very beginning of the file has an integer that tells us the number of holes within the file, so the offset is removing that, so once I print it, it prints everything correctly. Then I check if there are holes in the helper array I created, if there are, then I want the animal's id to be that id and I am trying to seek to the line with the first -1 age to put my updated animal's information there, and then writing it to the file. The last for-loop is just me shifting up the available holes. Oh and as for opening the file, I am using r+b for reading and writing. Thank you in advance!

Comment: How did you open the file? What arguments did you pass to `fopen()`? It seems like the file was opened in append mode.

Comment: I stated in the next to last sentence I used "r+b" which I read is the most appropriate way to open when modifying the file the way I am intending.

Comment: Okay then, could you make a [mcve]?

Comment: Should `ani.id -1` be in parentheses?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know what that is..

Comment: @user3376654 Click on the link to find out.

Comment: That's a possibility that I am calculating my offset wrong.

Comment: that last for() loop in the posted code will shift the data to an earlier entry in the availableholes array, But is fails to 'clear' the last entry, so now there will be 2 duplicate entries, then 3 duplicate entries,  Only more duplicate entry for each time that posted code is called

Comment: I suspect this line: `int offset = ((sizeof(int) + sizeof(ani)) * ani.id -1);` should be: `int offset = ((sizeof(int) + sizeof(ani)) * (ani.id -1));`

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use `sizeof(availableHoles)` to iterate on the array.  You are in a function that receives `availableHoles` as a pointer, its size is irrelevant to the number of holes.

Pass the number of elements of this array as a separate argument.

Using the FILE streams in read/write mode is tricky, do you call `fseek()` systematically between accesses in read mode and write mode?

Post the calling code, the function `addingAnimal` alone is not enough to investigate your problem.

Comment: I believe you're referring to my for-loop at the very end, that is just to update the empty holes. That portion is working correctly to my understanding, it's me seeking to the right line of the file I am having trouble with.

Comment: @user3376654 No it's not working correctly. If you don't believe that then put a print statement inside the `for` loop. You should find it doesn't print out the number of times you intended the loop to run for. It may or may not be the root cause of your problem but it certainly is wrong and should be fixed to remove that possibility.